# How to use $getField in update MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a simple mongoDB document:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5c8eccc1caa187d17ca6ed16"),
  city: 'ALPINE',
  zip: '35014',
  loc: { y: 33.331165, x: 86.208934 },
  pop: 3062,
  state: 'AL'
}
```

The only thing I want to do is to add a new property `population` and set it with a value from `pop` property.

I've tried to use `$getField` like this: `updateOne({}, {$set: {"population": { $getField: "pop" }}})`. But the result is too straightforward xD

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5c8eccc1caa187d17ca6ed16"),
  city: 'ALPINE',
  zip: '35014',
  loc: { y: 33.331165, x: 86.208934 },
  pop: 3062,
  state: 'AL',
  population: { '$getField': 'pop' }
}
```

So how can I set `population` field to value from `pop` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this, without `$getField`:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "population": "$pop"
    }
  }
])
```

Here's the working [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3FMd0lHQxgp).